# Limit point interval

Tags: limits, analysis

Is the following true?

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.

$p$ is a limit point of $A\cap (p,\infty)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ $p$ is a limit point of $A \cap [p,\infty)$.

Proof(try): $„\Rightarrow“:$ Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $p$. Then there exists an $x \in A\cap (p,\infty)\subset A\cap [p,\infty)$ with $x \in U$ and $x \neq p$.

$“\Leftarrow“:$ $U$ again open neighborhood of $p$. Then there exists $x \in A\cap [p,\infty)$ with $x \in U$ and $x \neq p$. Hence $x \in A \cap (p,\infty)$.

Comment: My thought is that being a limit point is immaterial of whether the point is in the set or not (by definition), so the claim is indeed true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p$ is a limit point of a set $S$ $\iff$

every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point of $S$ other than $p$$\iff$

every  neighborhood of $p$  contains a point of $S\bigcup\{p\}$ other than $p$.

Now apply this property to your problem!